# Static site generator with dynamic components

Tags: php, python, ruby, jekyll

I'm looking for a good static site generator. I'm looking into either [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) / [Octopress](http://octopress.org) (Ruby) or maybe [Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/en/) or [PieCrust](http://bolt80.com/piecrust/) (PHP). I only have one thing that holds me back:

How do I create a sidebar widget that reads data from a JSON file *at build/compile time* and generate a static page based from the data? A particular use case is when I have a JSON file of events and I want to show them on a static page as a list of events of the week on a sidebar.

I know I could simply use client-side Javascript to load and process that JSON file and then manipulate the DOM but I am sure that this is not a good idea.

Currently, I'm using [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com) and I placed this custom code as part of the template. (Not ideal, I know. Didn't bother to fix it since I'm planning to migrate away from PyroCMS anyway.)

I prefer to use Jekyll (really functional) or Phrozn or PieCrust (because I can reuse my previous PHP code) but I cannot see how to create a semi-dynamic page like the one I described above. I'm open to other static site generators as well -- as long as they are in PHP, Ruby, or Python.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write Jekyll plugin to do this, probably a tag. If you put the JSON in a directory called _data, the skeleton of a tag plugin would be something like:

```
module Jekyll
  class JsonEventsTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      super
        # Open & Parse JSON file somthing like
        @events = JSON.parse(File.read("_data/events.json"));
      end

      def render(context)
        # loop over @events, format into HTML and return the result
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('sidebar_events', Jekyll::JsonEventsTag)
```

You could then call the tag in a layout as

```
{% sidebar_events %}
```

and when the site was built that would be replaced with your formatted-from-JSON list.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. So in Jekyll terminology, they are called `tags`. So I should now learn to create a Jekyll plugin that will output `tags`. Thank you. I'm now reading http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/.

Comment: There a few kinds of plugins, and this example is a tag -- which is really based on a library called Liquid. You can also use another kind of plugin called a "generator", for instance, to create entire pages (category pages being the prime example).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Now I know where to continue studying.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found that Phrozn seems to be able to do it.

http://www.phrozn.info/en/documentation/providers/﻿

I hope to hear more from Jekyll's perspective though.